# How to use a php ajax form in a color box?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, forms, colorbox

I have a login form in (login.php). It call a separate sample.php via ajax, and sample.php returns it the value and the Javascript will show the relevant message depending on the php return value. It works perfectly fine in a normal webpage. But when I display the form in color box (in test.php). The javascript/jquery failed to run. I have research abit about this by using ajaxform, but how exactly do i do it? Please advise me some keywords for me to research further :(, i am stucked.

test.php:

```
$(".ajax").colorbox();
<a href="" class=ajax>Login</a>
```

This is my ajax function:

```
function login()
{
hideshow('loading',1);
error(0);

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://utourpia.me/php/login_submit.php",     
    data: $('#loginForm').serialize(),
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(msg){

        if(!(msg.status))
        {
            error(1,msg.txt);
        }
        else location.replace(msg.txt);

        hideshow('loading',0);
    }
});
}
```

This is my jQuery:

```
$('#loginForm').submit(function(e) {
            login();
            e.preventDefault(); 
        });
```

This is my form:

```
<form id=loginForm method=post action="">

<label for=email class=email>Email:</label>
<input name=email type=text size=20 maxlength=40/>

<label for="password" class="password">Password:</label>
<input name="password" type="password" size="20" maxlength="40" />

<input class="login" type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" />
</form>

<div id="error"></div>
```

login_submit.php

```
<?php
require_once('../lib/connections/db.php');
include('../lib/functions/functions.php');
session_start();
$location_id = $_SESSION['location_id'];

$email = $_POST['email'];

$query = mysql_query('SELECT username FROM users WHERE email = "'.secureInput($email).'"') or die (mysql_error());

        if(mysql_num_rows($query) == 1)
        {
            $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
            $username = $row['username'];
        }

$returnURL1 = 'http://utourpia.me/php/places.php?id='.$location_id.'&username='.$username;
$returnURL2 = 'http://utourpia.me/php/myprofile.php?username='.$username;
$returnURL3 = 'http://utourpia.me';
$returnURL4 = 'http://utourpia.me/php/dreamtrip.php';

//For login

    // we check if everything is filled in and perform checks

    if(!$_POST['email'] || !$_POST['password'])
    {
        die(msg(0,"Email and / or password fields empty!"));
    }

    else
        {
            $res = login($_POST['email'],$_POST['password'],$username);
                if ($res == 1){
                    die(msg(0,"Email and / or password incorrect!"));
                }
                if ($res == 2){
                    die(msg(0,"Sorry! Your account has been suspended!"));
                }
                if ($res == 3){
                    die(msg(0,"Sorry! Your account has not been activated. Please check your email's inbox or spam folder for a link to activate your account."));
                }
                if ($res == 99){

                    if ($_SESSION['login_submit']=="places.php")
                    {
                    echo(msg(1,$returnURL1));
                    }
                    else if ($_SESSION['login_submit']=="myprofile.php")
                    {
                    echo(msg(1,$returnURL2));
                    }
                    else if ($_SESSION['login_submit']=="home.php")
                    {
                    echo(msg(1,$returnURL3));
                    }
                    else if ($_SESSION['login_submit']=="dreamtrip.php")
                    {
                    echo(msg(1,$returnURL4));
                    }
                }
        }

    function msg($status,$txt)
    {
        return '{"status":'.$status.',"txt":"'.$txt.'"}';
    }
```

?>

Comment: So what is the error in your code? where you got the problem.

Comment: javascript/jquery wont execute in colorbox. When i click submit, it just go back to login.php

Comment: but it works perfectly fine outside of colorbox

Comment: remove the else part `else location.replace(msg.txt);` from your code in ajax.

Comment: hmm, i think javascript never run at all. you can see demo here at http://utourpia.me/php/dreamtrip.php
when you click the tick at every picture, login color box will show up.
but when you access http://utourpia.me/php/login_for_color_box.php, it works fine.

Comment: Ok, I got your problem. and the solution I am posting in the answer.

Comment: it's good to hear from you! :)

Answer (score 0):

1. First thing you need to change in the form tag:

   Wright only above code. because you have given the method and URL that's why it refresh the page.
2. Replace your jquery code `$('#loginForm').submit(function(e) {` this code replace by `$('.login').click(function(e) {`.
3. Why are you using the `replace` method in the ajax success function is gives the error. remove else part.
4. location object does't have the replace method. if you want to redirect to user on success then use the `location.href="your link";`.

Make these changes and then check.

Comment: hi, i have reeedit the post and added login_submit.php. i think jquery never run at all, when i clicked it, e.preventdefault never run.

btw, is there any other way other than using location.href? because i am using login_submit.php to run the logic and return different link.

Comment: @CongLeong if you jquery is not running then how your colorbox is open. means your jquery is working.

Comment: yup, what i meant is that when i open up the color box, there is a login form right, and when password isnt correct/field empty, jquery will actually show the relevant error message in the form. this works when i open up the login form directly, but not when i open it in the color box.

Comment: that's mean i am running jquery after the colorbox is opened up